# Joining different rows on the same table with different critera

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I tried asking around and googling and I have ended up with a query that kills the DB in every possible sense.

I have 3 tables:

`jiraissue` keeps information about jira tickets (who its assigned to).

`changegroup` this keeps change date, the id of the ticket being changed and an id to the change details.

`changeitem` contains the change id, the change field and new/old values.

I want the following output:

[time_taken_to_resolve],[assigned_date],[resolve_date],[jira_ticket_details_from_jiraissue]

Criteria is jiraissue.ASSIGNEE value.

I came up with the following:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,a.assigned_date,b.resolved_date),a.*, b.* 
FROM jiraissue 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT changegroup.CREATED as "assigned_date",changegroup.issueid as jid 
    FROM changegroup 
    JOIN changeitem ON changegroup.ID = changeitem.groupid 
    WHERE changeitem.FIELD="assignee"
    GROUP BY changegroup.issueid 
    ORDER BY changegroup.CREATED DESC 
) as a ON a.jid = jiraissue.id 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT changegroup.CREATED as "resolved_date", changegroup.issueid as jid 
    FROM changegroup 
    JOIN jiraissue on changegroup.issueid = jiraissue.ID 
    JOIN changeitem ON changegroup.ID = changeitem.groupid 
    WHERE changeitem.FIELD="status" AND changeitem.NEWVALUE=5
    GROUP BY changegroup.issueid 
    ORDER BY changegroup.CREATED DESC 
) as b ON b.jid = jiraissue.id 
WHERE jiraissue.ASSIGNEE = "gangsta";
```

The above query works if I use a specific `jiraissue.id`, but not if I search by `jiraissue.ASSIGNEE` (it carries on crunching).

Also I am interested in the latest resolved and assigned dates, there could be many, but i want the last one of each.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should analyze your indexes. I think you have one by jiraissue.id, but none by jiraissue.ASSIGNEE. For the last resolved and assigned dates you can use max() in your joins.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this, seems to do the trick:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,a.assigned_date,b.resolved_date),a.*, b.*,jiraissue.*
FROM jiraissue
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  MAX(changegroup.CREATED) as "assigned_date",changegroup.issueid as jid
  FROM changegroup 
  JOIN jiraissue as ji1 ON changegroup.issueid=ji1.id 
  JOIN changeitem ON changegroup.ID = changeitem.groupid 
  WHERE changeitem.FIELD="assignee" AND ji1.ASSIGNEE="gangsta" AND issuetype = 5 AND PRIORITY = 4
  GROUP BY changegroup.issueid
) as a ON a.jid = jiraissue.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  MAX(changegroup.CREATED) as "resolved_date", changegroup.issueid as jid
  FROM changegroup 
  JOIN jiraissue as ji2 ON changegroup.issueid=ji2.id 
  JOIN changeitem ON changegroup.ID = changeitem.groupid 
  WHERE changeitem.FIELD="status" AND changeitem.NEWVALUE=5  AND ji2.ASSIGNEE="gangsta" AND issuetype = 5 AND PRIORITY = 4
  GROUP BY changegroup.issueid
) as b ON b.jid = jiraissue.id
ORDER BY b.resolved_date DESC;
```